# Quarkus project Graal Native using Maven

Tags: maven, quarkus, graalvm-native-image

I am trying can create a native executable using: `./mvnw package -Pnative`
The command is running from the last 2 hours but it's still not complete.

I have attempted it multiple times, I have restarted the system too but nothing helped till now.

Complete Log:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------< org.acme:code-with-quarkus >---------------------
[INFO] Building code-with-quarkus 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ code-with-quarkus ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ code-with-quarkus ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ code-with-quarkus ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/testuser/Desktop/quarkus-rest/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ code-with-quarkus ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ code-with-quarkus ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running org.acme.ExampleResourceTest
2020-06-01 06:38:37,777 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Quarkus 1.4.2.Final started in 4.412s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8081
2020-06-01 06:38:37,852 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile test activated.
2020-06-01 06:38:37,855 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, resteasy]
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 9.505 s - in org.acme.ExampleResourceTest
2020-06-01 06:38:41,842 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Quarkus stopped in 0.068s
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ code-with-quarkus ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.4.2.Final:build (default) @ code-with-quarkus ---
[INFO] [org.jboss.threads] JBoss Threads version 3.1.1.Final
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.JarResultBuildStep] Building native image source jar: /home/testuser/Desktop/quarkus-rest/target/code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar/code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] Building native image from /home/testuser/Desktop/quarkus-rest/target/code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar/code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] Running Quarkus native-image plugin on GraalVM Version 20.1.0 (Java Version 11.0.7)
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] /usr/lib/jvm/graalvm-ce-java11-20.1.0/bin/native-image -J-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -J-Dsun.nio.ch.maxUpdateArraySize=100 -J-Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxLogDelegateFactory -J-Dvertx.disableDnsResolver=true -J-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=DISABLED -J-Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder=1 -J-Duser.language=en -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 --initialize-at-build-time= -H:InitialCollectionPolicy=com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.CollectionPolicy$BySpaceAndTime -H:+JNI -jar code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar -H:FallbackThreshold=0 -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces -H:-AddAllCharsets -H:-IncludeAllTimeZones -H:EnableURLProtocols=http -H:NativeLinkerOption=-no-pie --no-server -H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature -H:+StackTrace code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner
-H:IncludeAllTimeZones and -H:IncludeTimeZones are now deprecated. Native-image includes all timezonesby default.
[code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:41959]    classlist:  18,228.62 ms,  0.74 GB
[code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:41959]        (cap):   3,989.95 ms,  0.74 GB
[code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:41959]        setup:  12,572.12 ms,  0.74 GB
06:41:15,775 INFO  [org.jbo.threads] JBoss Threads version 3.1.1.Final
[code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:41959]     (clinit):  10,836.94 ms,  0.75 GB
[code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:41959]   (typeflow): 198,049.68 ms,  0.75 GB
[code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:41959]    (objects): 499,552.27 ms,  0.75 GB
[code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:41959]   (features):  13,579.92 ms,  0.75 GB
[code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:41959]     analysis: 756,771.78 ms,  0.75 GB
[code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:41959]     universe:  66,599.46 ms,  0.74 GB
[code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:41959]      (parse): 221,467.49 ms,  0.65 GB
[code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:41959]     (inline): 2,025,552.89 ms,  0.67 GB
```

Versions of different technologies:

1. OS: Ubuntu 20.04-VB-64bit
2. GraalVM runtime: OpenJDK Runtime
3. Environment GraalVM CE 20.1.0  Native-Image: GraalVM Version 20.1.0
   (Java Version 11.0.7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (on 1.4 and the upcoming 1.5), Quarkus is only compatible with GraaVM 19.3.1 (LTS) and 20.0.0, you can see that in the Getting Started page: https://quarkus.io/get-started/

Both Java 8 and Java 11 versions are supported.

20.1 should be supported in 1.6.

Can you try with 20.0.0?

In addition to version, I see that the memory available for native-image is really low, 0.67 GB. You didn't specify any memory limit (Xmx) for a native-image command so I assume you run it on a low memory device (or inside a low memory container). The native image needs a lot of memory (4GB or more), I think it's why it never ends

Comment: I have tried versions 20 and 19 both. but the same problem.

Comment: I see that the memory available for native-image is really low, `0.67 GB` . You didn't specify any memory limit (Xmx) for native-image command so I assume you run it on a low memory device (or inside a low memory container).
Native image needs a lot of memory (4GB or more), I think it's why it never ends ...

Comment: After increasing the memory I am able to create the image. Thank you.